Fastest RPC Endpoint for Binance Smart Chain
What is the fastest RPC endpoint for accessing the Binance Smart Chain, and are there alternative methods of communication with this blockchain? Additionally, does the performance of these methods vary depending on geographical location?


What is the fastest RPC endpoint for accessing the Binance Smart Chain, and are there alternative methods of communication with this blockchain?

Fastest, as in terms of latency, is always a local node. Run your local node and you get zero latency and infinite speed.
If you want to your transactions to be included first, then you need to run your own validator and do MEV by having your own transactions taking priority over other users.

Additionally, does the performance of these methods vary depending on geographical location?

Most good blockchains, like BNB Smart Chain, are geographically well-distributed. There is not a single central server.


What is the fastest RPC endpoint for accessing the Binance Smart Chain, and are there alternative methods of communication with this blockchain?

Well the fastest RPC most times would be really on your own self-hosted node, but it's surely a hard and costly task, so it's better to use some RPC providers. There are many of them and some might even have latency not really higher than your own node!
I'm using GetBlock.io and I' pretty good with them!

Additionally, does the performance of these methods vary depending on geographical location?

Well the performance of your RPC does really depend on the geografical factor, however most providers have globally distributed nodes, so you'll find what you need! I'm using GetBlock's German and US nodes
